# how to send values to zero or more repetitions parameter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set values and call service for zero or more repetitions parameter.
here is my json request parameter:

```
{
"itemId":"1",
"sendTo":"a001",
"sendTo":"b001",
"description":"sample item"
}
```

In controller, i have an array having values a001,b001.

```
var sendToArray =[];
sendToArray = // assigning a001,b001 here
```

In service,

```
data.payload = {
                itemId":itemId,
                "sendTo":sendTo,
                "sendTo":sendTo,
                "description":description
            };
```

for more than one "sendTo" parameter, how to assign values.

Comment: You can't have 2 keys with the same name in an object.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to send more than one value on a parameter, use an array:

```
data.payload = {
  "itemId":"1",
  "sendTo":["a001","b001"],
  "description":"sample item"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response. it worked for me.